# Magento 2 rest API: filter category by name

Tags: php, magento, magento2, rest

I need to find categories by name using Magento 2 rest api.
I use `/all/V1/categories` and filters but I can't get it to work.
Here's the code:

```php
$url = "https://*******/index.php/rest";
$token_url= $url."/V1/integration/admin/token";
  
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => USERNAME, "password" => PASSWORD);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $token_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
    ));
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$adminToken=  json_decode($token);
$headers = array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer '.$adminToken);

$ch = curl_init();

$apiUrl = $url."/all/V1/categories";

$data = [
    "searchCriteria" => [
        "filterGroups" => [
            "filters" => [
                "fieldName" => "category",
                "value" => 'CATEGORY NAME',
                "condition_type" => 'eq'
            ]
        ]
    ],
];

$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$response = json_decode($response, TRUE);
curl_close($ch);
```

This is the error that appears after launching the code:

```
array:3 [▼ "message" => ""%fieldName" is required."  "parameters" => array:1 [▼ "fieldName" => "category" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get categories by name with Magento 2 rest api by adding search criteria to endpoint `rest/all/V1/categories/list`. The request to api should look like this:

```
https://website.com/rest/all/V1/categories/list?searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=name&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcondition_type%5D=eq&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=category_name
```

Replace `website.com` with the url of your website and `category_name` with the search term for category.

If the search string also should match part of the category name, you can use `like` instead of `eq`.

For more information, refer to: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/performing-searches.html